# ` Unexpected token 'const'` webpack and babel not transpiling code in WEBPACK VAR INJECTION section

Tags: webpack, babeljs, webpacker, react-on-rails

We have a Rails 5 project that uses react_on_rails, and thus webpack (via the webpacker gem) and babel.  We are running testing using capybara webkit and we are getting this error when using the webkit_debug javascript driver.

```
http://localhost:3001/packs-test/kronos-bundle-b399226ff352220cce47.js|80403|SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'const'
```

Both our production and test webpacks have `const` variables in the `WEBPACK VAR INJECTION` section of the pack, but I think modern browsers are ok with `let` and `const` now so we haven't noticed.

Our `.babelrc` looks like:

```
{
  "presets": [
    [
      "env",
      {
        "modules": false,
        "targets": {
          "node": "current",
          "browsers": ["last 2 versions", "safari >= 7"],
          "uglify": true
        },
        "useBuiltIns": true
      }
    ],
    "es2015",
    "react",
    "stage-1"
  ],
  "plugins": [
    "transform-flow-strip-types",
    "syntax-dynamic-import",
    "transform-object-rest-spread",
    [
      "transform-class-properties",
      {
        "spec": true
      }
    ]
  ]
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out there were two issues here that were biting me.  First, there were two modules we were using that we not being transformed, so I had to add explict includes for them in webpack to pass them to babel-loader:

```
  {
    test: /\.jsx?$/,
    include: [path.resolve(__dirname, '../../node_modules/')],
    use: [
      {
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        options: {
          cacheDirectory: 'tmp/cache/webpacker/babel-loader'
        }
      }
    ]
  }
```

Once i did that, I found that both webpack and poltergeist needed still more conversion to get to generic ES5.  To do this, we needed to add the es5-shim to our entry point.  I chose to do this by modifying our `/config/webpack/test.js` file like this:

```
const environment = require('./environment');

const config = environment.toWebpackConfig();

const entry = config.entry['kronos-bundle'];

config.entry = {
  'kronos-bundle': ['es5-shim/es5-shim', 'babel-polyfill', entry]
};

module.exports = config;
```

Not sure if there is a better way to load that ployfill but this now works.

Comment: Removing legacy `exclude: /node_modules/` worked for me